# a counting problem from a reality show

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 6 people and 3 rooms. Each person is equally likely to enter one of the rooms. What is the probability that finally there are 2 people in each of the 3 rooms?

I came up with the question when I was watching a reality show (it was a scenario in the show). I tried to solve it, but the result shows that I must have been overcounting. I wonder if someone can help me solve it. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and where you think you went wrong ?

Comment: Also, how many people can a room hold ?

Comment: As a way to get started, consider 1) how many ways there are for two people of the six to end up in one room., and 2) how many ways are there for two of the remaining four to end up in a different room.

Comment: Each assignment of people to rooms has the same probability: $(1/3)^6=1/729$.  So you can count the assignments meeting your criteria... there are ${6\choose{2}}=15$ ways to choose two people for the first room, times ${4\choose{2}}=6$ ways to choose two people for the second room (and the remaining two people must be in the third room).  The resulting probability is $90/729=10/81$.

Answer (score 4):

Your (finite and equiprobable) sample space is $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}^6$. How is it interpreted? Well, if the event is $(1,2,2,1,3,3)$, it means that the 1st and 4th person go to the room 1, the 2nd and the 3rd to the room 2 and the 5th and the 6th to the room 3. So its cardinality is $|\Omega|=3^6=729$.

Let $A:$"there are 2 people in each of the 3 rooms",
how many events achieve $A$? You need to count the anagrams with $(1,1,2,2,3,3)$, i.e. $|A|=\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}=90$. So the probability is $\mathbf{P}(A)=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{90}{729}$.

Comment: $$=\frac{10}{81}$$